# Где хостится база данных?

Tags: база-данных, хостинг

У меня есть приложение для нескольких компьютеров в офисе, которые используют для работы одну и ту же базу данных: получают из нее данные, сохраняют в нее данные... Есть сотни материалов, как использовать/брать/записывать данные в базу и нет материалов, где эту базу размешать. Нужно ли платить за хостинг этой базы, могут ли 100 + ПК подключаться к этой базе и работать с ней и так далее. То есть, на самые простые вопросы не так-то легко найти ответ. Сталкиваюсь с базами впервые и по результатам двухдневного поиска решился задать этот вопрос. Ткните носом... Только не в поганый Гугловский FireBase...

Comment: Где подходит по всем нужным параметрам и где нормально работает, там и размещайте, что тут ещё сказать-то

Comment: Ну хостите локально, вместе с приложением.

Comment: Дак а вопрос какой? "где эту базу размешать" - это?

Comment: Ставите в офисе на один из компьютеров, лучше вообще на отдельный (сервер) ПО самой СУБД, в приложении указывается адрес этого сервера, где размещена БД. А так как адреса используются обычные IP, то и сервер может быть и не на физическом компе, а где угодно в интернете

Comment: И да, 100 ПК конечно могут подключаться, хоть тысячи. Тут вопрос только в том, тянет ли железо вашего сервера требуемую нагрузку.

Comment: А если не локально? Не в офисе, а, скажем... Где?..

Comment: @Xyanight, если не локально, то на любом хостинге, тысячи их. Вот в ответе вам reg.ru советуют, тоже вариант. Не понятно почему вы считаете это "не ответом".

Answer (score 3):

Все зависит от ваших потребностей. От того какие данные вы там будете хранить зависит выбор типа БД ( SQL, NOSQL ). Какой общий объем данных, скорость роста объема данных - от этих параметров и отталкивайтесь. Если SQL то это MySql, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL,.  Возможно ваше приложение должно работать с несколькими БД одновременно - такое тоже возможно. Есть облачные БД, но это зависит от политики компании, многие не захотят выкладывать например персональные или бухгалтерские данные в облака. Свой сервер надежнее.

Если вы уже решили что это будут сервер на стороне - берете любой сайт который предоставляет серверы в аренду, для примера здесь https://www.reg.ru/dedicated/ . Выбираете параметры сервера которые вам необходимы. После чего скачиваете ПО БД для примера https://www.postgresql.org/ , устанавливаете его на арендованный вами сервер, вот собственно и все.

Есть хостинги с уже установленной БД например здесь https://www.reg.ru/hosting/#econom .

Можете использовать облако oracle, вот документация https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/index.html

Comment: В общем, я так понял, ответов нет....

Comment: @Xyanight, это ответ, один из возможных. Чем конкретно он вас не устраивает?

Comment: Вы же сами сказали, что сталкиваетесь с базами впервые. Невозможно предложить эффективное решение на все случае жизни. Попробуйте сформулировать список требований к вашей задаче. Старайтесь идти от более простого к сложному, а не наоборот. При выборе СУБД для начала поэкспериментируйте с ними в офисе. Предпочтительнее некоммеческие СУБД MySQL, PostgreSQL  и др. Именно их вам придется использовать в случае хостинга. Пробные версии коммерческих СУБД ограничены по числу одновременных сессий пользователей. Вам всё подсказали верно, не забудьте и о защите информации в случае хостинга.

Comment: Эффективность решения часто определяется грамотно построенным приложением, а не только выбранной технологией. Можно и с sqlite получить приемлемый результат, а можно и из пушки по воробьям промахнуться. За хостинг вам однозначно придётся платить. Подробнее о нем узнаете на reg.ru.